# Implementing Content Types in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am evaluating DNN as an alternative to WSS. In WSS, I can define content types (basically a group of columns), enter the content from the back-end, and display it using web parts.

This is very useful to display a list of items with a predefined format, which is really what I am looking for.

Is there any way I can implement this functionality in DNN? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you specify a little more? It is hard to connect the dots if you haven't used WSS/Sharepoint for a while... Do you want to show a list of files, HTML content, data entry forms or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core [Form & List](http://dnnfnl.codeplex.com/) module allows you to define a data format and display it via a template.